# While connecting to database I am getting "driver not found" error. How can we resolve this issue?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

while executing DB queries in PAF I am getting "driver not found" error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

User needs to download driver executable jar  file for corresponding database and  add that jar file in project class path. To put driver jar file in class path follow below steps:

Click on the dropdown next to the Run button on the IDE  and select “Run Configurations…”

Select any of the java application from left pane select the tab arguments ->Dependencies--->select class path entries-->click on add external jars button

Select the driver jar file from the folder  where it is saved and add to dependencies. click on 'Apply'  and close button

You have to set the drivername  in db.driver of init file.
Eg: if the db is oracle, you can give db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.